# Can i use Kibana UI for client's ? Is it open source?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am new to kibana the requirement is to build an analytical dashboard, so we are thinking of uploading the data into elastic search and **give access to only visualization of kibana** to build reports and use the different dashboards. I have googled and found some links for building custom dashboards using **kibana plugin** but We don't need any customization so we wanted to use the same kibana UI. Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch and Kibana are both open-source.

If you want to prevent your users from read/writing to cluster but allow them to create visualisations and dashboards then you can do so by using a basic license and setting up Role-based access control. You'll need to give them full access to `.kibana` index. Have a look at [Elastic subscriptions](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions) to understand the different types of licenses (subscriptions).

If they only want to view and `not` create visualisations/dashboards, then create a RO (read-only) user with limited privileges i.e read-all but no-write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

> Can i use Kibana UI for client's ? Is it open source?

Yes, Kibana is open source. You need a server to host Kibana for free, or you can buy some special option like 10 nodes ES server and `Kibana` with `SAML` (Platinium plan).
Check: https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions

The name you are looking for is `Elastic stack` not solo `Kibana`. 
For example `Kibana` needs `Elasticsearch` always.

Some features are in paid versions only, or in some free additional plugins.